# Looping Text label in C#?

Tags: c#, winforms, loops, timer, visual-c#-express-2010

i have a timer that changes a label's text each tick. For some reson, it stop and does not continue looping. Why?

```
        private int count = 0;
    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            string[] arr4 = new string[3]; // 4 
            arr4[0] = "one";
            arr4[1] = "two";
            arr4[2] = "three";

            if (count == 4)
            {
                count = 0;
            }
            toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = arr4[count];
            count++;
    }
```

Comment: Ticks are very short. Perhaps your UI rendering can't keep up with it?

Comment: i have edited the tick to 5000 ms or 5 seconds

Comment: Also, you don't check if count is 3 because doing `arr4[3]` will result in an index out-of-bounds exception.

Comment: yes, i get an error after the whole thing loops

Comment: You should use `if(count > 2)` instead of `if(count == 4)`.

Comment: that is it...thanks! Also, when my form loads, the label's text is blank. Then it goes to arr4[0]. When it loops again, the text starts at arr[0]. Why is the text blank first, and how do i fix it?

Comment: What kind of timer are you using, e.g. `System.Timers.Timer`?  That has an `AutoReset` property that must be set to `true` if you want it to continue raising events after the first.  Is the timer running in a separate thread from your main UI thread?  There are issues in updating UI elements from threads that don't own them.

Comment: i fixed it, but can you answer my other question...above your comment

Comment: @AVD please add as an answer so you can get +rep!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Also, when my form loads, the label's text is blank. Then it goes to arr4[0]. When it loops again, the text starts at arr[0]. Why is the text blank first, and how do i fix it?

Looks like your original question was answered in the comments. I'll answer your second question from the comments.

Your `timer1_Tick` event doesn't execute immediately when your program starts. The first time it executes is after 5000ms, in your case. So the label will show blank at first, then change to the value of arr4[0]. If you don't want that, you could:

- set the value of the label in the designer at design time
- set the value of the label in the constructor at run time
- pull the creation of the array out of the timer tick event so you're not recreating it every 5 seconds, make it a class variable, and create it in the constructor and then set the label to arr4[0] immediately after creating it